# Android navigation component not going top previous fragment on back press, instead it reload the current fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using 2 bottom navigation views and both have separate nav graphs and a different navGraph for auth-related fragments.
So I have 3 activities in-app and multiple fragments
The navigation component is not going back to the previous fragment on the back press, it reloads the current fragment again and again. Is there any better approach for this and how can I change its behavior.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragNavHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_nav_graph" />
```

Comment: navigation 2.4.0 or 2.3.x? 2.3.x' s sample code can do this.

Comment: activity?.findNavController(R.id.fragNavHost)?.popBackStack()

Comment: "is not going back to previous fragment on back press, it reload the current fragment again and again" - it sounds like you have a `LiveData` you `observe` in the fragment that you are going back to that is calling `navigate()`. Is that correct? Can you include the code for that fragment you are trying to go back to?

Comment: @ianhanniballake you are right. i think live data observer is creating the problem. Using custom single live event will solve the problem.  viewModel.loginResponse.observe(this, {
            when (it) {
                is NetworkResult.Success -> { findNavController().navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginToSignupTypes())
                }